# How to match each position of a matrix with a value of variable in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have spatial data. I coordinated it and then calculate the spatial distance between each pair of locations and store them as a matrix. Now, I would like to add two columns to this matrix based on the values of its values (by the position in the matrix). For example, Assume I have the following matrix (M).

```
 M =   
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]

   [1,] 1     2    5    10
   [2,] 1     3    5    15
   [3,] 2     3    10   15
```

Now, I would like to add two new columns to this matrix.

The first new column is should be based on the value (each entry of the matrix) of the first column of the matrix. As follow:

M[1,1] = 1 (this is the first location) which corresponding to the first value of my variable (meuse$zinc). So, the fifth column of `M` should be based on the entire of the first column of `M`. That is:

`mesue$zinc[[M[1,1]]` and so on for all the entries of the first column of `M`.

For example,

```
M =   
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]   [,5]

   [1,] 1     2    5    10    mesue$zinc[[M[1,1]]
   [2,] 1     3    5    15    mesue$zinc[[M[2,1]]
   [3,] 2     3    10   15    mesue$zinc[[M[3,1]]
```

Then, the same for the second new column (`6` column of `M`). Such that:

```
M =   
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]   [,5]                  [,6] 

   [1,] 1     2    5    10    mesue$zinc[[M[1,1]]    mesue$zinc[[M[1,2]]

   [2,] 1     3    5    15    mesue$zinc[[M[2,1]]   mesue$zinc[[M[2,2]]
   [3,] 2     3    10   15    mesue$zinc[[M[3,1]]   mesue$zinc[[M[3,2]]
```

Here is the code:

```
library(sp)
  data("meuse")
  dist <- spDists(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")
  d <- expand.grid(1:nrow(dist),1:nrow(dist))
  d$dist <- apply(d,1,function(r)dist[r[1],r[2]])
  dd <- as.matrix(d)
  dimnames(dd) <- NULL
  dd <- dd[dd[,1] < dd[,2],]
  dd <- dd[order(dd[,1]),]
  dd
```

**I tried this:**

```
dpair1 <- dd[,1]
  dpair2 <- dd[,2]
  dpair <- list(dpair1, dpair2)
  i <- dpair[[1]]
  ii <- dpair[[2]]
```

Then I used `lapply`

```
dat <- unlist(lapply(dpair, function(x) meuse$zinc[[x[[1]][[i]]]]))
```

but got an error

```
Error in x[[1]][[i]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve.
Nevertheless, the line below will give you a **list** with the values (of the columns) you want to append to your matrix (so it seems):

```r
> dat <- lapply(dpair, function(x) meuse$zinc[x])
```

You already have everything what you need (apparently) in the "dpair" list.
It is also not clear (at least to me) why you want to 'unlist' the list.
You can append the values to your matrix by doing:

```r
> for (i in 1:length(dat)){
+    dd = cbind(dd,dat[[i]])
+    }
```

which runs ok, giving me as (the head of the) answer (of your "dd" matrix):

```r
> head(dd)
     [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2  147.0884 1022 1141
[2,]    1    3  440.7263 1022  640
[3,]    1    4  889.3523 1022  257
[4,]    1    5  953.7662 1022  269
[5,]    1    6 1025.6077 1022  281
[6,]    1    7  797.5861 1022  346
```

Comment: Thanks, it is correct. Will `meuse$zinc[x]` takes the values from `dpair[[1]]` and `dpair[[2]]` respectively? I thought I must write like this: meuse$zinc[dpair[[1]]` otherwise it will not work. I really learned a new thing.

Comment: Indeed! @Mary. When you use `lapply(dpair, function(x) ...` every element of the list 'dpair' goes as the 'x' in your function. If you want to use iterators/numerals instead of elements (and still get the same result) I'd do something like `dat <- lapply(1:length(dpair), function(x) meuse$zinc[ dpair[[x]] ])`... but as you can see the alternative in the answer is simpler and "cleaner".

Comment: Thank you so much. I only knew the second code `dat <- lapply(1:length(dpair)..` but it is great to learn a new thing.